# Onclick event of button is not invoking Javascript method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser

I have a form with buttons on it. When I call the Javascript method using the `onclick` event of the button, it works in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer. But when I use Firefox, the `onclick` event of the button doesn't invoke the Javascript method.

```
function openHistory()
{
    window.open("frmCLogHistory.aspx?txtCLogID="+document.all['<%=txtCLogID.ClientID %>'].value, 'abc', 'fullscreen=no,top=10,left=100,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no, directories=no,location=no,width=800,height=630,titlebar=no');
}
</script>



<input type="button" name="showHistory" value="Show History"  
onclick="javascript:openHistory()" style="width:120px;"  class="GVButton" />
```

Comment: post some codes what you've tried so far

Comment: sachin i have shared the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function openHistory()
{
  var element= document.getElementById('<%= txtCLogID.ClientID %>').value;
  window.open("frmCLogHistory.aspx?txtCLogID="+element, 'abc', 'fullscreen=no,top=10,left=100,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,   directories=no,location=no,width=800,height=630,titlebar=no');
}
```

Comment: Thanks it working perfect.                                                                The World is Gold if U R Bold!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the code works in Internet Explorer and Chrome, but not in Firefox, maybe there is a popup blocker working in Firefox that stops your `window.open()` call? Add some debugging code to your function, say:

```
function openHistory()
{
    alert('Firing window.open');
    window.open( <... url ... > );
}
```

See if you get the alert, which means your function is firing, and it's just the `window.open()` call that fails.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 1

Use as follows

```
 <input type="button" name="showHistory" value="Show History" class="GVButton"
     onclick="javascript:return openHistory()" style="width:120px;"  />
```

Java-Script Code

```
  function openHistory()
 {
    var pageName="frmCLogHistory.aspx?";
        pageName+="txtCLogID="+document.getElementById('<%=txtCLogID.ClientID %>').value;
    var options ="fullscreen=no,top=10,left=100,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,directories=no,location=no,width=800,height=630,titlebar=no";
    window.open(pageName,'abc',options);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: no ihave used the onclick event just check it  by looking at code @Shekhar

Comment: **`document.all` is a proprietary Microsoft extension to the W3C-standard. `getElementById` is standard - use that.**

Comment: Since the button is not an `asp:Button` but a regular `input type="button"`, there is no `OnClientClick`.

Comment: I did not downvote you, I only commented that it wasn't an ASP button.